# Terminal is showing the same error exactly twice when compiling the C code

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, system, gcc-warning

I started C programming today in my windows operating system and downloaded and installed the GCC compiler exactly as described in the Visual Studio Code Website (Instructions - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw). Also, I have set the environment variables correctly. Everything is running smooth. For the note, I installed the GCC compiler using MSYS2. The mingw64 is being used.

OS - Windows 10
Used - Mingw64 version

So I have willingly done an error to check my code and the error is being printed twice in the terminal and it's very disturbing. To compile and get the errors I'm using

```
gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -Werror testing.c -o out
```

I want to get rid of getting two errors at once for the same problem and just get one single error. Assitance will be appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int s = 76;

    printf("%f", s);

    return 0;
}
```

The above shown in the code

```
Acer Aspire 5@LAPTOP-IDII92M3 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/New folder
```

```
$ gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic -Werror testing.c -o out

testing.c: In function 'main':

testing.c:7:14: error: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Werror=format=]

    7 |     printf("%f", s);
      |             ~^   ~
      |              |   |
      |              |   int
      |              double
      |             %d
testing.c:7:14: error: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Werror=format=]

    7 |     printf("%f", s);
      |             ~^   ~
      |              |   |
      |              |   int
      |              double
      |             %d
cc1.exe: all warnings being treated as errors
```

As shown above I get the same exact error message twice. I can send a picture under a request.

*In a note I tried the same error in my Linux virtual machine. However, the compiler is not the same when it comes to Linux right? So, in the Linux system, I don't get the error twice. I just get the error only once which is the right way of getting it.*

Comment: Why worry about that? Fix the problem and you won't get *any*.

Comment: It's totally sane to be concerned about the quality of a programming tool. Printing one error message twice by a compiler is not a sign of good quality. - That said, I can't reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Yes I'm finding a way to fix the problem and couldn't figure out a way Weather Vane :)

Comment: Totally agreed with you Armali. I even tried the CMD command line and I get the error twice. I think it's something wrong with the compiler. I should try installing from another source.

Comment: See [gcc bug 92292](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92292).

Comment: Please do not post images.  Rather select/copy/paste the image as text into your question

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP posted images rather than text.

Comment: Yeah @ssbssa I see they have found the error. But they haven't provided a correct solution for it right? I may try mingw32 version and see whether it's working or not.

Comment: UPDATE - Have been trying a lot of compiler versions to solve this problem but I'm getting the same duplicate error problem in Windows 10. If someone can test this out and update whether they are getting this same error in Windows it will be much appreciated. Compiler version doesn't matter. Just want to know the output.

Comment: I found a solution by myself for this issue. The compiler version does not really matter "sometimes" if we can do the thing correctly. I installed the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSI) and installed the GCC compiler from the Unix terminal. Now I can use that terminal in VS code (my usual programming space) smoothly like I used to while I was using Linux. For anyone who might find this useful I will add the installing instructions site [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#manual-installation-steps)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution by myself for this issue. The compiler version does not really matter "sometimes" if we can do the thing correctly. I installed the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSI) and installed the GCC compiler from the Unix terminal. Now I can use that terminal in VS code (my usual programming space) smoothly as I used to while I was using Linux. For anyone who might find this useful I will add the installing instructions site [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#manual-installation-steps)

I was able to get rid of the above problem I had and I'm using Windows for C programming smoothly.